# Cannot read property 'value' of null angular reactive form get value

Tags: javascript, json, angular, typescript

```
{
  "estimate_number": "2020-1234",
  "brand": "PF",
  "floor": "Laminaat",
  "floor_type": "Normaal",
  "plint_type": "Hoog",
  "floor_installer": {
    "id": "14",
    "name": "Maestro"
  },
  "address": {
    "street": "Straatnaam 19",
    "city": "Amsterdam",
    "postal_code": "1111AB",
    "province": "Noord-Holland"
  },
  "notes": "Test note"
}
```

why does `const city = this.addEventForm.get('address.city').value;` give me a value (in this case Amsterdam) but `const floorInstaller = this.addEventForm.get('floor_installer.id').value;` gives me the following error in developer console saying `ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null at CalendarComponent.push..`

This object is the result of a reactive angular form.

The FormBuilder code used to make up the form:

```
        // FormBuilder
        const datesGroup = this.fb.group({
            start_date: '',
            start_time: { hour: 7, minute: 30 },
            end_date: '',
            end_time: { hour: 17, minute: 30 },
        });

        const addressGroup = this.fb.group({
            street: '',
            city: '',
            postal_code: '',
            province: '',
        });

        this.addEventForm = this.fb.group({
            event_dates: datesGroup,
            estimate_number: '',
            brand: '',
            floor: '',
            floor_type: '',
            plint_type: '',
            floor_installer: { id: '', name: '', },
            address: addressGroup,
            notes: '',
        });
```

Comment: Can share the form definition to have more clarity. The value shown, is it form value?

Comment: Added it to the main post

Comment: What value are your getting for `this.addEventForm.get('floor_installer').value`?

Comment: that returns the object like shown [here](https://i.imgur.com/TRQuomK.png).
It only gives me the error when I add .name or .id to floor_installer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi think you may get the value with below snippet:

```
this.addEventForm.get("address").get("city").value
```

Code snippet I tried:

```
const addressGroup = this.fb.group({
  city: ""
});

this.addEventForm = this.fb.group({
  address: this.fb.group({
    city: ""
  })
});
getVAlue() {
 console.log(this.addEventForm.get("address").get("city").value);
}
```

HTML:

```
<form [formGroup]="addEventForm">
 <div formGroupName="address">
    <input formControlName="city" >
 </div>
</form>
<button (click)="getVAlue()">Get</button>
```

Hope this will help. I just took only city. You may include all the controls.

Comment: Thanks for you answer but sadly that wasn't exactly my issue. I could get values fine EXCEPT for the floor_installer nested values. Sorry if my question wasn't clear enough!

Comment: You can try this for that :                            this.addEventForm.get("floor_installer").value.id
this.addEventForm.get("floor_installer").value.name. If this won't work, then you need to create one more formGroup.

Comment: That worked, thank you so very much! Please add it to your answer as I marked it as correct

Comment: Great to here this from you... !

Answer (score 0):

May be the direct object `{ id: '', name: '', }` isn't recognized by the `get()` function. Try assigning `floor_installer` it's own form builder group.

```js
const floorInstallerGroup = this.fb.group({
  id: '',
  name: ''
});

this.addEventForm = this.fb.group({
.
.
.
  floor_installer: floorInstallerGroup,
.
.
}
```